# Need help finding the minimal distance between two points

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Hello I've been doing an exercise  but I don't know how to find the answer. I need your help, please.

**Question**

Let Q(1,1,4) be a point on the space and P(x,y,z) any point on the line Delta : (x,y,z) = (3,0,4) + t (2,1,-1), where t belongs to **R.** For which value of t is the distance between point Q and point P minimal?

**What I've done**

[I determined the coordinates of P](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH50i.jpg)

[I determined the length of the director vector d and the components of PQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slPA5.jpg)

[I determined the expression of PQ×d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcZnd.jpg)

[I found the expression of the distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC81K.jpg)

Comment: The point $q$ is currently in $R^4$ and your line is in $R^3$. Please clarify what $Q$ is.

Comment: I am sorry  the coordinates of Q(1,1,4)

Comment: $4-(4-t)=t, $ not $-t$ as you wrote

Comment: This is essentially the same problem as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3466934/265466. The only difference is a minor one—the point is not at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

To stick to your geometric approach using orthogonality you may proceed as follows:

- Let $P_t = P + td$ with $d = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$.
- $||Q-P_t||$ is minimal iff $(Q-P_t) \perp d$.

Hence,

$$(Q-P_t) \perp d \Leftrightarrow (Q-P-td)\cdot d = 0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (Q-P)\cdot d =t||d||^2 \Leftrightarrow \frac{(Q-P)\cdot d}{||d||^2} =t $$

Plugging in the given values gives

$$t = \frac{\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}}{2+1+1} = -\frac 12$$

Answer (score 0):

The square of the distance between $P$ and $Q$ is

$((3+2t)-1)^2+((t)-1)^2+((4-t)-4)^2=6t^2+6t+5=\frac32(2t+1)^2+\frac72.$

This is minimized when $2t+1=0$ or $t=-\frac12$.